# Getting 'source file is corrupted' error when trying to install Genymotion

Tags: android, genymotion

I just downloaded Genymotion setup file from [**this**](https://www.genymotion.com/download-trial/) link. I downloaded the trial version, the one without virtualbox.

I then tried to execute the setup file, but I get the following error:

[image]

If I click on **Ignore** then I keep getting the same error message (just with a different filename).

I tried t download the same file again and execute the setup file once. I get the same error.

Comment: https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/#installer-integrity

Comment: @MuratK.Yes, that was it! I downloaded for a third time and I finally got a checksum match. If you put your comment in an answer together with some short explanation I will mark it as an answer.

Comment: It was a wild guess. No idea why the download got corrupted in the first place.